# Avoid overwriting on array

Tags: c++

Is there any way where overwritting of the array can be avoided? In my implementation I have to write data to an buffer/array of fixed size say `buff[100]` and will be using `buff[100]` whenever I want to o/p data I will write to `buff[100]` (i.e will you again use the same `buff[100]`) the next time when I use `buff[100]` it should append the data.

Comment: If you put periods after each sentence, we might be able to understand you better.  Complete sentences and good spelling really do help, especially when you're asking for help.  Why would anyone spend more effort answering your question that you did asking it?

Comment: code please (formatted please)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maintain an index into the array.  When the length of the data you want to write plus the index is greater than or equal to 100, write out the buffer and the data.  Otherwise, shove the data into the buffer at that offset and add the length of the data to the index.

For example, assuming that the following variables are in scope:

```
#define BUFFER_LENGTH 100
char buffer[BUFFER_LENGTH];
int buffer_index;
int output_fd;
```

You could have a function like this:

```
void write_buffered(char *data, int data_length)
{
    if (data_length + buffer_index >= BUFFER_LENGTH) {
        write(output_fd, buffer, buffer_index);
        write(output_fd, data, data_length);
        buffer_index = 0;
        return;
    }

    memcpy(&buffer[buffer_index], data, data_length);
    buffer_index += data_length;
}
```

This is written C-style because I know C better than C++, but the basic principles are sound.  Obviously, avoid the use of global variables and alter the `write()` calls to whatever call you are already using.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention C++, why don't you use a std::vector or similar container? It would be **much** simpler and less error-prone.